# Jquery append an array of object values to the right div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array of objects like this

```
var TLPics = [{
   id: 2141,
   Picture: "/postimg/20181102_134013.jpg",
   userpostid: 4891
}, {
   id: 2142,
   Picture: "/postimg/20181102_134053.jpg",
   userpostid: 4891
}, {
   id: 2143,
   Picture: "/postimg/20181102_133944.jpg",
   userpostid: 4892
}]
```

And then I have several divs' with data attribute data-id like this

```
<div id="TLF" class="c2">
   <div id="ttimgs" class="mygalleryx lidf2" data-id="4891"> </div>
</div>
<div id="TLF" class="c2">
   <div id="ttimgs" class="mygalleryx lidf2" data-id="4892"> </div>
</div>
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is to filter the array and the resulting array get the image data source from picture: apply to the image and then append the image to the right div with an identical  userpostid in relation to the div data-id attr. eg userpostid=4891 append to dive with data-id = 4891.

So far I have tried the code below but I have problems with it creating images in divs' that don't have identical data-id 's

```
function checkpics(e) {
   var x = parseInt(e);
   var appendTLpic = TLPics.filter(element => element.userpostid === x);
   $(".lidf2").each(function() {
      var thisid = $(this).data('id')
      $(TLPics).each(function() {
         if (thisid == this.userpostid) {
            $('[data-id="' + thisid + '"]').append('<a><img  class="userpictz lazyload imgz xp"  alt="" data-views="" data-likes="" src="' + this.Picture + '" style=" display:inline-block"/></a>');
         }
      });
   });
   appendTLpic = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue you have here is that you're duplicating both the `#TLF` and `#ttimgs` `id` attributes when they *must* be unique. Change them to classes.

Then you can loop through each `.ttimgs` element and `find()` the related object in the array by matching the `data-id` attribute to the `userpostid` property, before appending the new `img`. Try this:

```js
var TLPics = [{
  id: 2141,
  Picture: "/postimg/20181102_134013.jpg",
  userpostid: 4891
}, {
  id: 2142,
  Picture: "/postimg/20181102_134053.jpg",
  userpostid: 4891
}, {
  id: 2143,
  Picture: "/postimg/20181102_133944.jpg",
  userpostid: 4892
}]

$('.ttimgs').each(function() {
  var src = TLPics.find(x => x.userpostid === $(this).data('id')).Picture;
  $(this).append(`<img class="userpictz lazyload imgz xp" alt="" data-views="" data-likes="" src="${src}" />`);
});
```

```css
.userpictz { 
  display: inline-block; 
  
  /* just for this demo... */
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TLF c2">
  <div class="ttimgs mygalleryx lidf2" data-id="4891"></div>
</div>
<div class="TLF c2">
  <div class="ttimgs mygalleryx lidf2" data-id="4892"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, my final objective is to append all pictures that have the same userpostid into that particular div. So far your answer is only appending one of each. as you see in my array it has two objects that have the same userpostidid. which ultimately be appended to that same div. I hope I am being clear enough for you to help me.

Comment: I would start a new question for that, providing clear data which shows the duplicates, as well as the HTML output you want to create.

Comment: Ok fine @Rory McCrossan I didn't mention that on my development environment  it is giving me an error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Picture' of undefined

Comment: @Roy McCrossan And why would I start a new question. We building on this solution. I simply asked you as per data provided above that I have two userpostids that should appear as append pictures in in that particular div. I am not happy with your reply. because that was my initial question which was not fully addressed.

Comment: It's because on SO you should ask one question per post. Extended requests asked after an answer is posted (which aren't mentioned in the question itself) should be avoided. If you read the question guidelines it's advised to put all relevant information regarding your current situation and what you want to achieve within the question to avoid this happening.

Comment: With regard to the 'Picture is undefined' error, that must be because the `TLPics` array is not in the format you've posted in the question, as you can see the above works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187863/discussion-between-marcos-j-d-junior-and-rory-mccrossan).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error this is the code I came up with and it achieved my desired results from my question. this may not be the cleanest of code

```js
    var TLPics = [{
  id: 2141,
  Picture: "/postimg/20181102_134013.jpg",
  userpostid: 4891
}, {
  id: 2142,
  Picture: "/postimg/20181102_134053.jpg",
  userpostid: 4891
}, {
  id: 2143,
  Picture: "/postimg/20181102_133944.jpg",
  userpostid: 4892
}]
    
    var x;
    var appendTLpic = [];
    $(".mygalleryx").each(function () {
  
    x = $(this).data('id')

    appendTLpic = TLPics.filter(element => element.userpostid === x);

    $(appendTLpic).each(function () {
        var src = this.Picture

        $(`.lidf2[data-id=${x}]`).append(`<img class="userpictz lazyload imgz xp" alt="" data-views="" data-likes="" src="${src}" />`);
   
    });
 
    });
```

```css
.userpictz { 
  display: inline-block; 
  
  /* just for this demo... */
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TLF c2">
  <div class="ttimgs mygalleryx lidf2" data-id="4891"></div>
</div>
<div class="TLF c2">
  <div class="ttimgs mygalleryx lidf2" data-id="4892"></div>
</div>
```

When dealing with asp.net web-forms I would have simply solved this with a nested repeater where i get my images from a data-source controlled by the main repeater's hiddenfeild value. Now because my new application demands I have to use Ajax hense this complication.

So I create for each loop for my div with class .mygalleryx then retrieve each divs data-id. now I filter my array TLPics using my data-id variable x. I then nest a for each function for my new filtered array which I retrieve the picture. Now within my new filtered array each function I append my image to the matching div dat-id using my initial variable x and I am done. I am still learning I do wish to be corrected. But this answer has resolved my issue.